# Describing quantitative change in print. Which to mention first, initial or current value?

Tags: writing-style

Is there a linguistic convention regarding whether to mention initial or current value first when describing change?

I believe analysis of cognitive processing (retention, attention and retrieval) demands during reading would recommend mentioning the initial value first. (The price of bread changed from $1 to $2) because it facilitates constructing a model as you read. Requirement to keep final value in memory until initial value is read might increase reading difficulty/comprehension.

However, "The price of bread changed to $2 from $1" seems equally common in current newspapers and magazines.

Comment: English provides multiple ways to express both orders, and there's also statistics and graphics. There is no standard -- you use what you think will work.

Comment: The choice is often based on what the writer wishes to emphasize.

Comment: What, pray tell, is a cognitive analysis??

Comment: I recall reading that the WSJ style sheet calls for the most recent value first. Style sheets of course change.

Comment: Chronology has the great advantage of logic. Don't need *respectively* here: For breakfast, lunch, and dinner I'm partial to a bagel with coffee, soup and sandwich, and a plate of cooked food with herbal tea and cookies.

Comment: If "from to to" has been found to facilitate reading (constructing a model) that would override style sheet fashion.

Comment: I agree with @Zan700. Intuitively a "from to to" style makes for smoother reading and comprehension.

Comment: If Zan700 has a reference to support "has been found to facilitate" it would be useful.